# Rejected from Apple Mac Store because using Xamarin implementation of NEVPNManager

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.mac

Today we got rejected from Apple Mac Store because we used Xamarin implementation of NEVPNManager in our Mac application.

> Your app includes VPN services but does not use the NEVPNManager API to deliver these services.

Previously we had the VPN functionality in an objective c library (that was binded) and we got accepted. Now we removed the objective c library and used the xamarin implementation and we got rejected.

Why did Apple reject us? @Xamarin are you using NEVPNManager in your implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the answer on Xamarin Forum:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/328214?

Thanks to @Chris Hamons for the help!

Solution:

Adding `--link_flags="-framework NetworkExtension"` to Additional MMP Arguments in Project Options -> Build -> Mac Build fixed the issue.

In theory those should be added automatically. Seems like a potential bug.

Comment: Your answer will become useless if the linked page goes down. Please share the relevant parts here.

Comment: Update: Edited my answer with the solution.